# Fat arrow usage with map

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

JavaScript newbie here. While trying to use Arrray.map with fat arrow, I am getting compilation errors. Below is my sample code along with the error.

```js
var employeesWithComplexLocation = [{
  "name": "jon",
  "location": {
    "country": "usa",
    "city": "austin"
  }
}, {
  "name": "jane",
  "location": {
    "country": "usa",
    "city": "houston"
  }
}, {
  "name": "mary",
  "location": {
    "country": "usa",
    "city": "dallas"
  }
}];

var employeesWithOnlyCity = employeesWithComplexLocation.map(function(element) {
  return {
    name: element.name,
    location: element.location.city
  };
});


console.log(employeesWithOnlyCity);
console.log('Now using fat arrow:')

employeesWithOnlyCity = employeesWithComplexLocation.map(e => {
  name: e.name,
  location: e.location.city
});

console.log(employeesWithOnlyCity);
```

Array.map works as expected with anonymous function, but gives below error when I use fat arrow instead.

```
employeesWithOnlyCity = employeesWithComplexLocation.map(e => {
  name: e.name,
  location: e.location.city
});

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The fat arrow works fine with Array.every, or Array.filter. Not sure what I am missing here with Array.map

Comment: could you try `e => {return {name:e.name, location:e.location.city};}`

Comment: It's either a single expression `(param,...) => expression` or one or multiple statements enclosed in curly braces `(param, ...) => { statements }` [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Simply enclosing in parenthesis should fix it too `e => ({
  name: e.name,
  location: e.location.city
})` it becomes an expression.

Comment: You're trying to return an anonymous object, but you're not forming one. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/76fr0vsL/1/) for you. You want to return an object.

Comment: Thanks all for the response. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your second usage is causing an error is because when using the javascript `=>` operator `{}` denotes a function body, not an object. The MDN article on Arrow functions mentions this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) and provides a link to a more thorough explaination ([here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)) that says this

> The rule in ES6 is that { immediately following an arrow is
>   always treated as the start of a block, never the start of an object.

If you need to return an object from an arrow function you should wrap the object in parentheses to let Javascript know not to expect a statement block.

```js
var test = e => ({test: e});
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(test("My Value"));
```

```html
Value: <span id="output">...</span>
```